# Cannonical or canonical?

Tags: spelling

I found spelling "cannonical" in this answer:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133641

My text editor marks it with red line as word error. Please tell me which form is correct, I have doubts.

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary?

Comment: @Void Yes, but still so many people viewed that answer and didn't edit it. This is why I have doubts.

Comment: @KarolZlot Yes, but they're talking about databases, not English usage.  They probably just didn't think it was important enough to be worth correcting. Also many of them may not be native English speakers either.

Comment: It seems strange to me to doubt the dictionaries, but trust random people on the Internet. Why do you think the answer you will get here is more credible than the dictionary?

Comment: @ColleenV It's not random people vs dictionaries. It's both vs only dictionaries. And people here are probably not that random. Now I have enough confirmation.

Comment: Random in what sense? Being fluent in English doesn’t necessarily mean one is a good speller.

Comment: @ColleenV  I thought: maybe there is something what dictionaries didn't catch. Many people viewed this question and no one answered that spelling "cannonical" is correct. This is enough confirmation for me. People here are not completely random, they have some interest in English language, it's enough for me.

Comment: When you search for an incorrectly spelt word in multiple dictionaries, and they redirect you to the correctly spelt word, with no mention of alternate spellings, you can rest assured that the word is misspelled. For example, if you look up ‘spelt’ you should be able to see in any reputable dictionary that it could also be spelt ‘spelled’. It is worthwhile to build your confidence in your ability to use reference books like dictionaries and find a definitive answer for simple things like misspelled words. You might not always find someone willing to do it for you.

Comment: @ColleenV OK, I see your point and agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, most dictionaries would agree on 'canonical' as the correct version.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canonical),
[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/canonical), [Oxford Learners Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition//canonical?q=canonical)